# redirect_to in action destroy ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following resources in db/config

```
resources :posts do

      resources :comments

    end
```

I have the following action destroy inside of my controller called Comment

```
  def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end
```

When I eliminate the comment rails redirect to the url of @post

```
example /posts/1
```

But I don't want to redirect to that url but  to

```
posts/1/comments
```

Comment: Rails is doing what you asked it to. If you want to redirect to a posts' comments, you need `post_comments_path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
redirect_to post_comments_path(@post)
```

---

From the command line, if you do `rake routes` it will show you:

```
       Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                                                                       Controller#Action
post_comments GET     /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                comments#index
```

The `post_comments` prefix lets you know that you have the two helpers available: `post_comments_path` and `post_comments_url` for generating the associated path or url.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. I am really newbie in rails